# Extracting a Number/Letter Code (C2, H3, W1 etc) from a text cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel list with course names and their number like this:

V3 Varikosis Masterclass

B3 Botulinumtoxin Premiumkurs, H2

M1 Mykologie Basiskurs [Digital], D1 Dermatoskopie Basiskurs [Digital]

B5 BTX Workshop (21.11.21) (sometimes there are random numbers that have nothing to do with the code like a date)

It's very messy since some people ordered two courses, so I can't just take the first two symbols from each cell. Is there a formula that finds and extracts a single letter and number combination from a string of text?

Comment: Use left() with find() to get up to the first space and test if it is only 2 characters with len()…

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any other cases e.g. max number of courses is 2 and comma and space is always the same it is rather straightforward.

```
=LEFT(A3,2)
=IFERROR(MID(A3,SEARCH(",",A3,1)+2,2),"")
```

[image]